# Is there a way to set the default view of Google Trends (related topics) to "Rising" instead of "Top"?

Tags: javascript, html

The code export that Google Trends provides you for the related topics query defaults to the "Top"  results. Is there a way to load the "Rising" results as the default? Here's the code I'm looking at:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  trends.embed.renderExploreWidget(
    "RELATED_TOPICS",
    {
      comparisonItem: [{ keyword: "cats", geo: "US", time: "now 7-d" }],
      category: 0,
      property: ""
    },
    {
      exploreQuery: "date=now%207-d&geo=US&q=cats",
      guestPath: "https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"
    }
  );
</script>
```

Here's a link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/google-trends-rmt87?file=/index.html:396-803